# What is default value for edittext field

Tags: android, ide, android-edittext

In android studio it is saying that private field principal and interest is never assigned, does anyone know what the default values are so I can assign them?

```
private EditText principal;
private EditText interest;
```

Comment: They are never assigned because you are never assigning them...

Comment: I know, I am asking for the default values

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense...

Comment: when you create a variable it always has a default value, for example: private double mPvalue = 0; the double variables default value is 0

Comment: They are set to `null` automatically. What Android Studio is telling you is that you are not doing `principal = ...`. `principal` will always be `null`.

Comment: thank you that's all I wanted to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Objects are initiated to `null`

The *default value*, as you call it, would be an empty instance of EditText.

So in your case you could (**!BUT SHOULDN'T!**)initiate them to `new EditText()` :

```
private EditText principal = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
private EditText interest = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
```

## Seriously don't do that ^ initiate them in as described below:

But that probably isn't what you want to do.  What you want to do is inflate them in `onCreate()` (if you're using activity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    principal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_principal);
    interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_interest);
    ...
}
```

Or `onCreateView()` (if you're using fragments):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.el_fragment, container, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    principal = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.et_principal);
    interest = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.et_interest);
    ...
    return root;
}
```

Comment: here is my code in its entirety, [link] (http://pastebin.com/NqmwQ6xR) how exactly do I inflate them

Comment: Look at line 26 and 27, do the same thing for the `principal` and `interest`. I did outline in in the answer above really well I think. One hint, you're using activity.

Comment: et_principal and et_interest are giving me symbol can't be resolved errors

Comment: et_principal and et_interest are the id's of the EditTexts in your layout XML, you probably named them diferently. Look in your XML.  I hope this will resolve your problem...

Comment: Remember that if you instance the EditText by yourself, every view needs the Activity context.

Comment: @Feantury oops, of course you're right. Fixed the answer, I just wanted to make it clear that you don't initiate those.

Answer (score 2):

Every Class attribute you create will be initialized to `null` unless you set the initial value. This is a Java feature, not Android. The only exception are the primitive types `(int, boolean, float...)` which will be initialized to their java initial values. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you have the initial values for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

By default the value of EditText will be null unless you initialize it